# Refer an object that is just after the current loop index in jinja

Tags: django, for-loop, jinja2

```
{% for i in posts %}

{% if i.loop.index++.user == i.user %}
<!-- Do something -->
{% endif %}

{% endfor %}
```

`posts` is the variable that is being looped, it has a ForeignKey that is `user`.
`i.loop.index` is evaluated as `i.0`, `i.1`, `i.2` `...`, I want the index just after the current loop index, if the index is `i.0` I want `i.1`,
to achieve that I am doing this `{% if i.loop.index++.user %}`, which should be evaluated to `{% if i.1.user %}` if 0 is the index.

But it is not working

Any help is highly appreciated!

Thank you

Comment: `i.loop.index is evaluated as i.0` i is a post object and loop is an attribute in the model ?

Comment: No, index is an attribute of the loop, meaning it returns the current loop index

Comment: Could accessing loop.nextitem help? https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.0.x/templates/?highlight=nextitem#for